# Alfresco Community 4.2 Document Management

Tags: alfresco

Currently I have a task of exploring Alfresco Community 4.2.
What I need to do is to build a workflow that allows users to upload document, an admin to verify it, and other higher level users to allow the document to be released, how it is released is not my concern. e-mail notifications will also be sent to higher level users or admin when the document is about to expire.

I have downloaded the Alfresco Community 4.2 exe from their website, and install it in a Windows 7 32-bit laptop. But I cannot access to /alfresco and /share, I learnt that I need MySQL for this, so I'm currently installing this one, http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/ , am I correct?

And do I have to do all this separately, for example, first I need to set up users, then configure their restrictions, then move on to documents?

I'm really really new in this. I've searched Google but so far everything seems complicated to me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you are using installer which you seems to be you do not need to install anything separately. Alfresco installer comes with everything bundled into it's installation.
Unless you have specific requirement where you want to use MySQL instead of bundled postgres database.

Now For workflow one everything is up and running you can check various existing out of box workflows available with alfresco if any of that meet your requirement you can use that directly no other efforts required.

In case you feel none of those workflow meetup your requirement then you need to create your advance workflow.
http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Workflow

This link contains all you need to know regarding alfresco workflows.

Comment: Thank you for the link. The reason why I installed MySQL is because I cannot access /share and /alfresco. If I can just directly use postgres, how do I access to /share and /alfresco? The error is 'Unable to connect. can't establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:8080.' I just need to click on either these two to start using alfresco correct?

Comment: It's okay, I am able to log in to /alfresco, my mistake was I didn't start service. /share is still a problem though.